# Laravel: Access key value from json type string

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I got this data from request in Laravel

```
{"value":"QWS Welding Supply Solutions, Taylor Street","latitude":-27.4495148,"longitude":153.0696076}
```

but i am not able to access keys individually i.e value, latitude, longitude. I have tried **json_decode** but that's not working.

This is my controller method

```
public function saveLocation(Request $request){
    $location = $request->all();
    Location::create(['address'=>$location->value,'long'=>$location->longitude,'lat'=>$location->latitude]);
}
```

basically i want to save location data from request to database. in the $location object i got data that i pasted on top

Comment: show controller method and what you have tried so someone can help you to solve issue

Comment: Hi john I have updated the question

Comment: what you get if you dd($location ); i mean dd($request->all());

Comment: Does this work? `Location::create(['address'=>$request->value,'long'=>$request->longitude,'lat'=>$request->latitude]);`

Comment: If thats all your data on the database too you could do Location::create($request->all);
Otherwise just try to dd($request->all);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with simple json_decode but I resolved my issue by using json_decode inside foreach loop and then accessing key pair values

```
foreach (json_decode($location) as $key => $value) {
    if($key=="value")
        $obj['address'] = $value;
    else
        $obj[$key] = $value;
}
Location::create($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Json decode works properly for mentioned json.If `$location` return mentioned json then

```
$data='{"value":"QWS Welding Supply Solutions, Taylor Street","latitude":-27.4495148,"longitude":153.0696076}';

dd(json_decode($data)->latitude);
```

so it should be

```
public function saveLocation(Request $request){
    $location = json_decode($request->all());
    Location::create(['address'=>$location->value,'long'=>$location->longitude,'lat'=>$location->latitude]);
}
```

Comment: but i got "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" when i try to decode it

Comment: @AfzalAli.try sample test from my answer.so you can verifiy.are you sure $request->all return json

Answer (score 0):

If you have a json like this

```
{"value":"QWS Welding Supply Solutions, Taylor Street","latitude":-27.4495148,"longitude":153.0696076}
```

you can do like this to access the **values**

```
$json = {"value":"QWS Welding Supply Solutions, Taylor Street","latitude":-27.4495148,"latitude":153.0696076};
```

the you can access the values like this

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['value'];
echo $json['latitude'];
echo $json['latitude'];
```

I hope it helps some one